# MLE $\hat{\theta} = 0$ for a binomial distributed CDF?

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

Suppose 100 seeds were planted and it is recorded that $x < 11$ seeds germinated. Assuming a binomial model we obtain the following likelihood:
[binomial image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tq4b.png)

I believe the curve can be calculated with the following r-code:

```
curve(pbinom(11, 100, y), xname = "y")
```

We have that:

$$L(\theta) = \sum_{x=0}^{10} \binom{n}{x}\theta^x(1-\theta)^{n-x}$$

The MLE is $\hat{\theta}=0$
However, how do I calculate this MLE?

I have tried:

$$L(\theta;x) = \prod_{i=1}^{10}f(x_i;\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^{10}\sum_{x=0}^{10}\binom{n}{x}\theta^x(1-\theta)^{n-x} \\
\implies \sum_{x=0}^{10}\binom{n}{\prod_{i=1}^{10}x}\theta^{\sum_{i=1}^{10}x_i}(1-\theta)^{10n-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}$$

Then taking the logarithm:
$$\log L(\theta;x) = \log \left(\sum_{x=0}^{10}\binom{n}{\prod_{i=1}^{10}x}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{10}x_i\log \left(\sum_{x=0}^{10}\theta\right)+(10n-\sum_{i=1}^{10}x_i) \log \left(\sum_{x=0}^{10}(1-\theta)\right)$$

We know that the MLE of a binomial distribution is given as $\hat{\theta} = \frac{x}{n}$ so I cannot understand how the MLE for the likelihood is 0. I suppose my way of indexing summation and products is wrong here?

Taken from: Pawitan, Y. 2013. In All Likelihood: Statistical Modelling and Inference using Likelihood, pg 40

Comment: Clearly you have your $L(0)=1$, while $L(\theta) <1$ when $0 < \theta \le 1$ so the likelihood must be maximised with $\hat \theta=0$.

Comment: @Henry I don't follow the conclusion; how are you concluding $\hat{\theta} = 0$ based on the size of $\theta$ as $0 < \theta \le 1$?

Comment: $L$ is a function that maps the interval $[0, 1]$ to probabilities between $0$ and $1$. Henry has noted that the function equals $1$ at $\theta = 0$, and is strictly smaller than $1$ everywhere else. So $L$ is maximized at $\theta = 0$ with value $L(0)=1$.

Comment: @angryavian thanks for the addition; I presumed to find the likelihood we'd need to find the maximum by setting $f'(\theta) = 0$, as opposed to $f(0)$? something like $f'(\theta) = 0$ and $f''(\theta) < 0$ then I would know if a local maximum exists. -- I took a step back and it clicked. I was a little too caught in finding a complex solution that simpler ones would not satisfy.

Comment: It is possible for a function to have a maximum at one end of an interval without having a zero derivative there (in this case the derivative happens to be  $0$ there but it need not be in others)